# Linking wordpress blog to CodeIgniter View

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, codeigniter

Well, here's the deal. I have this site with a framework called codeigniter. It's a MVC framework in PHP. I'm trying to use the wordpress API in order to set up a view in CodeIgnite that uses the wordpress API to get blog posts.

so the blog is in `/wp-blog/`, and the codeigniter framework is set up in `/system/`. so in the codeigniter view, I call `require_once('/wp-blog/wp-load.php');` the wp-load file opens a config file with the database info on it. However, when i call it from my view, it doesn't work. However, when it's called from `/wp-blog/index.php`, it has no problem showing me the database

I don't know if it's a permissions issue. I'm clearly able to access the config file, because I get an error message that says `'username'@'localhost'` and the username is right.

so if they are both getting the same file, and both executing the same file with the `mysql_connect()` function, why would one only work from inside the blog, and one does not work?

Here's the error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'theuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Filename: wp-includes/wp-db.php
```

Comment: your whole solution sounds like a bad idea. You shouldn't be 'joining' a code igniter app to wordpress at that level.

Comment: I have to. My client has a blog, and wants it to appear integrated into the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is wrong. Your CodeIgniter controller needs to run a [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) request to the blog's [XML-RPC API endpoint](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support) and process the response, then display it as you need to.

A second option is to just use an iFrame on the page, although iFrames were outlawed at some point in 2005.