# Using Codeigniter functions inside Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

Is it possible to somehow use CodeIgniter functionality inside Wordpress ?
I have this setup :

```
localhost
 -myProject(CodeIgniter)
  -Wordpress
   -wp-content
    -themese
     -myTheme
```

Although most of the functionality of CodeIgniter app and the Wordpress blog are independent, yet there are certain statistics which I need to show on the header and sidebar all the pages be it app pages or the blog pages. These statistics come from a remote server's database and CodeIgniter is what I am using to connect and retrieve the database entries. At this stage of development, I can not change my blog software, so I need to find a way to use them in conjunction.

Comment: Add a private API to your Codeigniter site and call it from your WP site on your server. There's several libraries to add an API to CI.

Comment: @ourmandave Looks like that's the way I will have to go then.

Comment: This guy says it better than me... http://stackoverflow.com/a/8569754/3585500